# How to get Windows Mail (Vista) to send mail?

Tags: email, smtp, windows-vista

It's throwing a "Socket Error: 10060, Error Number: 0x800CCC0E" error on send attempts.  So far my googling and binging reveals that a lot of other people seem to have the problem, but none of the listed solutions help.  Note that this was a clean build just days ago, next to no software loaded yet.  Looking for more suggestions, here's what I've done so far:

- Updated to Vista SP2 (only change is that now the Nvidia graphics driver crashes if the machine is left unattended for a few minutes (even with screensaver/power management off) :-/  Weird and completely unhelpful side effect).
- Removed Norton (not my choice to install, when I installed the ASUS mobo drivers, it came along with).  Interfering AV apps seemed to be the most common issue that I found online so far, but removal didn't help me (simple removal of Norton worked for others).
- Tried turning off the windows firewall, no change.
- Found one post where typing the SMTP server name in all caps solved his problem (makes absolutely no sense to me whatsoever).  No change (as expected).

Trying to Telnet out to the SMTP service was used to confirm that it's not just Windows Mail.  Seem to be completely incapable of sourcing traffic with the SMTP destination port.  The same configuration works fine on the same ISP on a Windows XP box.  Unfortunately, the e-mail provider doesn't support the MSA port (it's SMTP-AUTH, but on only the standard SMTP port).

Comment: Well, still unable to get this working.  Last remaining option is a reformat, but the user prefers to suffer along with webmail rather than give up the machine to have the reformat/reinstall/reapply all service packs routine done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the Windows Live update/package (with "Windows Live Mail") has made the problem go away.  Windows Live Mail looks identical to Windows Mail, yet it actually works...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try other smtp servers or just your ISP/Mail provider's? Maybe you have been blocked for some reason?

If you're not blocked by your provider, I would suspect that something left from your antivirus installation is blocking SMTP traffic. I have seen many cases where the culprit was the antivirus program. Try to download and run the [Norton Removal Tool](http://service1.symantec.com/Support/tsgeninfo.nsf/docid/2005033108162039).

Comment: Seems to be all port 25 destinated traffic is affected.  I'll give the Norton Removal Tool a try!  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I have earthlink at home and it was giving me a similar error and the Tech guy finally went onto the computer and asked me to remove Norton. As soon as I did email was working again.

Comment: No go on that.  Still doesn't work after removal tool run.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

Usually port 25 is blocked by AV software and is labeled something like "prevent the spread of mass mailer worms." See if you can find an option like that and just disable it instead of removing your protection suite.

Comment: Oh, I intend on loading something different on there.  I was very annoyed when the ASUS driver CD auto-loaded it.  I believe in loading AV software, just not Norton!